# Assigning multiple columns in large DataFrame hangs forever / extremely slow

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to impute data in a large DataFrame. In the example below, `self.__PRICE_COLUMNS` has length ~300.

The following is extremely slow:

```py
    def _impute(self, df):
        prices = df[self.__PRICE_COLUMNS].ffill().bfill()
        print('The line below hangs forever')
        df[price_cols] = prices[price_cols]
        return df
```

This works fine, but I really don't want to use in-place operations.

```py
    def _impute(self, df):
        df[self.__PRICE_COLUMNS].ffill(inplace=True)
        df[self.__PRICE_COLUMNS].bfill(inplace=True)
        return df
```

It works when `self.__PRICE_COLUMS` has a smaller length (e.g. 20). There are no obvious memory leaks, but my cpu spins up to 100%.

Comment: Which line hangs? Above or below the print? You'll have 3 copies of the data frame columns in memory. Perhaps your system is heavily swapping to disk.

Comment: The line below the print. I have 512GB of memory and have confirmed it is not swapping (about 25GB/512GB used).